# What's the difference between an elementary cylinder and a cylinder?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading "Theory of Probability and Random Processes by Koralov and Sinai", in which it has the following definition.

[image]

To me the two sets are defined equivalently, what am I missing? Please provide an example such that a cylinder is not an elementary cylinder, or vice versa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **elementary cylinder**, the set $B$ is merely a product $A_1\times A_2 \times\cdots\times A_k$.

For a **cylinder**, $B$ need not be a product set, but could be something in the sigma-algebra generated by the product sets.

The notation $\mathcal G \times \cdots \times \mathcal G$ should be explained earlier as the product sigma-algebra.

Comment: I considered, but I couldn't find any set in $\:  ×  ⋯  ×   \,$ that cannot be represented by $\: A_1 ×  ⋯  ×  A_k\:\!$, with each $\: A_i ∈  \:\!$. Can you show me a counterexample?

Comment: @teepung An open disk in $\mathbb R^{2}$ belongs to  the product of the Borel sigma algebra with itself but it cannot be written as $A \times B$.

Comment: In case $\Omega$ is the space of sequences of length $2$, the $2$-element set $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is not a product set, but is the union of two $1$-element  product sets $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(1,1)\}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm that's a great example, Thanks!

Comment: @GEdgar true, nice example, too!